# Win8 store app - GridView doesn't displaying

Tags: gridview, binding, windows-8, windows

I am new to win 8 app development. Currently i am trying to build a simple gridview but however it doesn't display the item in the gridview.

XAML

```xml
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="gridv" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="488,149,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="704" Height="310">        
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Code

```cs
    public class MenuItem {
        public string Name;
        public MenuItem() {}       
    }


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        load();
    }

    void load() {
        List<MenuItem> Temp = new List<MenuItem>() 
             { new MenuItem() { Name = "test"},              
                   new MenuItem() { Name = "test 2" } };
        gridv.DataContext = Temp;                
    }
```

However the displayed item was like this:
gridview.MainPage+MenuItem
gridview.MainPage+MenuItem

Is it anything wrong on the binding in the XAML?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors.

First one is in XAML while declaring the `DataTemplate`. You forget to add `<GridView.ItemTemplate>....</GridView.ItemTemplate>` See the correct code.

```xml
<GridView x:Name="gridv" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="488,149,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="704" Height="310">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Second mistake is in `MenuItem` class. You must declare the value as property not as variable. Correct is `public string Name { get; set; }`, `public string Name;` is wrong.